# Jquery click event of a div in li element not fired in mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, android, css, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

Fixed: Finally I generate elements directly instead of being rendered by jQuery.

Updated2: It seems clear about the real issue. I did a couple of tests, only one fired that I insert a link in it. but I don't want to bind the whole li element but a div element in a li.

Updated: I did some modifications about positions of divs, it works in android now but mobile Safari even any elements in ul list.

The following works in desktop Safari and Chrome but not their mobile versions. Any ideas?

#### js:

```
$('#SubCategories > li .likeRibbon').live('click', function () {
   ......
});
```

#### html:

```
<ul id="SubCategories">
      <li id="st2" >          
       <div class="likeRibbon">Like?</div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

#### css:

```
#SubCategories .likeRibbon
{
    border-style: solid none solid none;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #565656;
    background-color: #565656;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #777, 0 -1px 0 black;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 2px 0 5px 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-40deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-40deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-40deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    right: -35px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Are the divs rotated when the page loads in the mobile browser?  Before any clicking I mean.

Comment: sorry mate, I don't think it's relevant to rotation after I did some change, please see updated info above, thanks.

Comment: @William, in which event you bind the click event to divs?

Comment: I bind it in "$('#menulist').live('pageinit', function (event)".

Comment: @William , please select the right answer. I am confused that for all the answers you are commented as good !! Or if you have an another anwser , please post it. - Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Add an empty onclick attribute to the element:

```
<ul id="SubCategories">
      <li id="st2" >          
       <div onclick="" class="likeRibbon">Like?</div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

[Link to jQuery issue that describes the problem](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677)

Comment: The suggestion to add `cursor: pointer` from that ticket is quite interesting.

Comment: that seems strange that ios safari needs onclick="" attribute. Did the cursor: pointer suggestion work? It did for me :/

Comment: @Adgezaza I haven't tested extensively, but I have used the cursor workaround successfully.

Comment: I read the ticket. I have a doubt that where we need to add the cursor:pointer ? Is it in the :hover class or normal class ?

Comment: I had this problem in Android browser and This solution worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to the way you are binding the click event as it works in desktop browser but it doesn't in mobile browsers.

Shall you wrap your code within the pageinit event?
[jQuery Mobile Events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#pageID").live('pageinit', function() {
   // do something here...
 });
</script>
```

Comment: @William , please select the right answer. I am confused that for all the answers you are commented as good !!

Comment: Sorry @smilyface, this issues is too old to remember for me, if you create a new ticket, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, just add

```
    *.classidentifier*{
      cursor:pointer;
    }
```

in the CSS for that class or id. This fixes the issue.