# JQuery click() event not applying to <span> in webkit

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, click, html

I have a `<span>` tag that I've applied a `.click()` event to, but it doesn't work on either of the Android phones I've tried. When it's clicked, the text just highlights momentarily, but nothing happens afterwards. I've also verified that it works on desktop and iPhones.

```
<span class="likeunlike" data-text="Unlike">{{#t}}Unlike{{/t}}</span>
```

And the `.click()` method

```
this.$el.find('.likeunlike').click(function() {
    //code here
}
```

I've seen some people on the 'net say that Android doesn't have an **onclick** event, but that seems odd to me.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do to get a clickable span working?

**EDIT 1:** I'm testing on an old Google phone, and nothing seems to work. Tried on a newer Android phone of a friend's (in both the default browser & Chrome) and the site worked fine. Oh, the joys of the fragmented Android ecosystem. :)

Comment: Instead of using `click` you could try `touchstart`

Comment: Thanks @ExplosionPills, but that didn't work either. I'm beginning to think the phone I'm using is the culprit.

Answer (score 4):

Add an empty `onclick` attribute to the span or apply `cursor: pointer` to the element in the style sheet. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692072/jquery-click-event-of-a-div-in-li-element-not-fired-in-mobile-safari/8696213#8696213).

Comment: The empty `onclick` attribute didn't work, nor did the `cursor: pointer` style sheet addition. I tried both suggestions individually and together. I appreciate the link you sent, and I have no idea why this still isn't working. I'm using an old Google phone by Samsung & don't have any other Android phones to test on. I love Android...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.tap()`:

```
this.$el.find('.likeunlike').on('tap click', function() {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either. The iPhone still works though.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old issue but I faced the same issue in safari browser of iphone and ipad. I don't know if the same solution will work for this issue too. The solution was writing `span.likeunlike` instead of `.likeunlike` :

```
this.$el.find('span.likeunlike').click(function() {
    //code here
}
```