# Span onclick not working in webkit (safari mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit

I have a clickable span that works perfectly on Android and desktop etc, but it does not work on iphones.

```
$('#spanname').on("click", function() {
/* do something */
});
```

I have tried touchstart, touchend and added hover pointers as per some other suggestions for this weird behaviour after researching, but nothing works.

Any ideas? If not, I guess I'll have to do away with the span and use a div.

(the reason I'm using a span is because I am using a large » instead of an arrow image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is check the silly and obvious things first. The device I was checking my updates on was actually pulling down an older iteration of the site and therefore wasn't showing my updates. The procedures did work, but only when I made sure I was actually looking at the correct version.

Apologies to anyone that took the time to look and also thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an empty onclick attribute to the span or apply cursor: pointer to the element in the style sheet. ;)

[More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692072/jquery-click-event-of-a-div-in-li-element-not-fired-in-mobile-safari/8696213#8696213)

Comment: Does your container receives any event that could prevents the click event for the span ?

Comment: Not until the arrow itself is clicked. When the arrow is clicked it displays the next image. There's a container, a div with the image inside and two arrows.

Comment: Hm not sure about that but let's try to bind your event like this, this is my last idea : $('body').on('click', 'yourspan', function(){ ... });

Comment: Lateek, I'm ever so sorry for wasting your time. The iPhone was loading up an old iteration of the site, so that's the reason nothing was working. It wasn't seeing my updates. Feel like such a dumbass. But thank you for your trouble. It is most appreciated.